# Downloading GeoTIFF files from Soilgrids 2.0 using Linux yields files without spatial information

Tags: geotiff-tiff, linux, soilgrids

I've been trying to download global GeoTIFF files from [this](https://files.isric.org/soilgrids/latest/data/) Soilgrids database in Linux using [this](https://git.wur.nl/isric/soilgrids/soilgrids.notebooks/-/blob/master/markdown/webdav_from_bash.md#to-download-a-global-geotiff-in-homolosine-projection) tutorial. The process seems to work, but when I try to use the files they have no associated spatial information and are essentially just pictures. I'm an undergrad who is new to coding and does not have access to ArcGIS Desktop.

Here's the output when I run the gdalinfo function on one of the faulty GeoTIFF files:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF

Files: ocs_0-5cm_mean_5000.tif

Size is 7962, 2902

Coordinate System is:

PROJCRS["Interrupted_Goode_Homolosine",

BASEGEOGCRS["GCS_WGS_1984_ellipse",

    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",

        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,

            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],

        ID["EPSG",6326]],

    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,

        ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]],

CONVERSION["unnamed",

    METHOD["Interrupted Goode Homolosine"]],

CS[Cartesian,2],

    AXIS["(E)",east,

        ORDER[1],

        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,

            ID["EPSG",9001]]],

    AXIS["(N)",north,

        ORDER[2],

        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,

            ID["EPSG",9001]]]]

Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2

Origin = (-19949750.000000000000000,8361000.000000000000000)

Pixel Size = (5000.000000000000000,-5000.000000000000000)

Metadata:

  AREA_OR_POINT=Area

  Code_version=v2.0.0
              Covariates=clm_wcl_srdyrsum,clm_wcl_s04rad,clm_wcl_p10tot,veg_mod_eviyravg,clm_wcl_p09tot,veg_mod_nppy15,    mor_env_demm,clm_wcl_s08rad,clm_wcl_srdyrstd,clm_wcl_s07rad,clm_wcl_bio19,clm_wcl_p05tot,clm_wcl_bio17,mo    r_mrg_twi,clm_mod_lstd03std,clm_mod_lstd04std,clm_wcl_bio16,clm_wcl_bio08,clm_mod_lstd09std,clm_mod_lstd1    1std,clm_wcl_bio18,mor_mrg_vdp,clm_wcl_p04tot,clm_mod_lstd05std,clm_mod_lstd12std,clm_mod_lstd10std,clm_m    od_lstd02std,clm_wcl_p12tot,clm_mod_lstd01std,veg_mod_evient,veg_mod_evirng,veg_mod_evimax,veg_mod_evievn    ,luc_gfc_trely10,mor_mrg_vbf

Litter_layers=FALSE

Model=Quantile Regression Forests

Model_type=ranger

Mtry=15

Number_trees=200

Outputs_version=RUN03

WoSIS_version=Data stream 7

Image Structure Metadata:

COMPRESSION=DEFLATE

INTERLEAVE=BAND

Corner Coordinates:

Upper Left  (-19949750.000, 8361000.000)

Lower Left  (-19949750.000,-6149000.000)

Upper Right (19860250.000, 8361000.000)

Lower Right (19860250.000,-6149000.000)

Center      (  -44750.000, 1106000.000) (  0d51'53.55"W,  9d56' 7.32"N)

Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Gray

NoData Value=-32768
```

Comment: Why not use the web services? QGIS can read them using https://maps.isric.org/mapserv?map=/map/ocs.map&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=-19948500.0,-6147449.0951699,19688885.757062882,8361000.0&CRS=EPSG:152160&WIDTH=1426&HEIGHT=895&LAYERS=ocs_0-30cm_mean&STYLES=&FORMAT=application/openlayers

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I need to extract data for a long CSV file of coordinates. I have a program that does this with GeoTIFF files. I have previously used it with WorldClim's .tif files, but it should work with any GeoTiff.

Comment: It looks like it has spatial information stored in a WKT2 representation. Can you maybe add more context how you access the TIFs?

Comment: ISRIC does not provide SoilGrids in the GeoTIFF format. You can either download the full maps in the VRT format or use the WCS [as suggested below](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/376998/21532). Apart from that, the CRS information posted in the question appears correct, if the file is faulty there must be another reason.

Answer (score 2):

Using the url below.

```
https://maps.isric.org/mapserv?map=/map/ocs.map&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=-19948500.0,-6147449.0951699,19688885.757062882,8361000.0&CRS=EPSG:152160&WIDTH=1426&HEIGHT=895&LAYERS=ocs_0-30cm_mean&STYLES=&FORMAT=application/openlayers
```

This can be easily loaded into QGIS (Windows/Linux/Mac)
[image]

Then export the area of interest you require as a GeoTiff

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your suggestion! When I try to save the files as .tif instead of VRT, I get the error "Attempt to create 0x0 dataset is illegal,sizes must be larger than zero." Do you have any suggestions on how to export in the highest resolution possible while avoiding this?

Answer (score 1):

You have do have spatial information on your file, on your post you have the following information:

```
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["Interrupted_Goode_Homolosine",
BASEGEOGCRS["GCS_WGS_1984_ellipse",
:
:
Origin = (-19949750.000000000000000,8361000.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (5000.000000000000000,-5000.000000000000000)
```

This is the minimal spatial information information necessary for you to work with  the file. The file is in `Goode Homolosine projection`, as indicated on the [Soilgrids FAQ - How can I use the Homolosine projection](https://www.isric.org/explore/soilgrids/faq-soilgrids#How_can_I_use_the_Homolosine_projection).

You can then transform the geotiff from the Goode Homolosine projection into EPSG:4326 using `gdalwrap` or `gdal_translate`

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 input.tif output.tif
```

This information concern projection transformation is indicated on the [soilgrids tutorial](https://git.wur.nl/isric/soilgrids/soilgrids.notebooks/-/blob/master/markdown/webdav_from_bash.md#to-download-a-global-geotiff-in-homolosine-projection).

Hope this helps, the proposed solution of [Mapperz](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/276/mapperz) is also a good way to get the maps, with the extra bonus of not requiring ArcGIS